# How to use test account on Google Play? GooglePlay always sees me as the purchaser

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I added a gmail account in the test input (in the Developer Console), I added my apk on my device, and I changed the account in `GooglePlay` app. But I always get the same error : "the purchaser cannot buy this item" as if I was using my developer account to test the purchase, which is not allowed. Does someone know how to test the app with the test user account?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set your account on the device (not just in the Google Play app) to your test account. Then you have to make sure that your test account is registered in your developer console (which you open using your publisher account). The most flexible approach is to set up a Google group and add that to the developer console, then accept your test account into the group.

EDIT: Here are the steps I use when testing an app that has Google licensing. It's all pretty much as described in the section [Setting Up the Testing Environment](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#test-env) of the documentation for setting up licensing.

- Upload the .apk to my account on Google Play. To test an upcoming release of an existing app, the .apk file with the new version code needs to be uploaded (but need not be published).
- Side-load the .apk onto my device.
- Make sure that the account on the device is either my publisher account or an account that I have registered the account to have testing access (this is found under "Setting" -> "Account Details" on the developer console).
- Set the Licensed Test Response to whatever I need for testing.
- Run the app on the device. It should receive the test response when it contacts the licensing server.

Note that all this is different from setting up Alpha and Beta testers. The details for that are described [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). This testing program is a different facility provided by Google where you actually publish alpha and/or beta .apk files, send invitations to users to opt-in as testers, and they access the test versions of the apps through Google Play. For that program, my understanding is that the publisher account cannot also be a tester account. Note that there are several caveats when using this program:

- Alpha- or beta-test apps will only appear in Google Play for testers that opt-in and not to any other users.
- A production APK is not required to publish an alpha- or beta-test app.
- It may take up to 24 hours after publishing for the test link to become active.

Comment: Thanks, I also add the test account in "Account and Synchronization" on my device, and unchecked the boxes referring to `Google Play` for the previous account, and let them checked for the test account, is that what you mean in your first sentence? About the `google group`, could you please explain me how to do that?

Comment: @Paul - Yes, what you did in the account settings sounds right. Regarding the Google groups approach, take a look at the Google docs on [beta testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) and on [testing in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html). Regarding the app itself, you can simply side-load the app onto your device and as long as the account is registered as a test account, it will receive whatever license validation response you set for the app in the developer console.

Comment: Thanks TedHopp, so the test user cannot try the app without being in the alpha group? I followed the steps, I uploaded a new apk to the alpha section, I sent an invitation and confirmed it with my test account. But I haven't received a link to download the app, or the app is not visible in google play (It says that only the tester could see it). When I try the apk on my device, I still get the previous message "the purchaser cannot buy ...". Would you know how to test the app from now?

Comment: @Paul - No, that's not quite right. If you side-load the app, you should be able to run it and receive the test response, provided Google Play thinks your account is a test account. You should not try buying the app through Google Play.

Comment: OK thanks, I will wait 24 hours to see if there are any changes. So, the only thing I did was upload the apk in the `alpha` section in the developer console, create a group and invite the test user, which confirmed the invitation. I will see tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: Thanks Ted for your help, unfortunately it still does not work, I opened a thread in the android developer group but it needs to be accepted by a moderator. By any chance, if you could describe in your message the steps that worked for you, it might show where I made a mistake?

Comment: @Paul - I added details of how we do testing.

Comment: Ted thank you very much, it works now, I had to remove the previous account from the list of account, not just uncheck the boxes related to Google Play. Thanks a lot for your answers.